# PHP/MySQL search specific value in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress, search

In a WordPress environment I'm creating pages that represent a company page.
These company pages sell certain brands. So I created a custom form in a metabox that let's the user dynamically add fields to add the amount of brands they sell. These values are stored in an array in my database.

The problem I'm having now is that I want to create some sort of filter. 
I created a page that shows all images of the possible brand logos. These logos are having a link with a custom value added to it (brandname).
For example:

```
<a href="somepage.php?brand='brandname'"><img src="brandname.jpg"></a>
```

On the page that follows I do a get request to retrieve the value added to the url. With this value I would like to show all the companies that are selling the brand.

The last part of this is the problem. I don't know how to search in an array with the value added to the URL.

So I figured I need an SQL statement to `SELECT` * `FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE` the database `meta_key` field `= 'brand'` and the `meta_value =` the `GET['brand']` from the url and found in the `array`.

-- UPDATE --
So I tried the solution from DiegoCoderPlus but give me not what I want:

```
global $post;
$merk = $_GET['merk'];
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = 'brand'");
foreach ($results as $result){
    $post_id = $result->post_id;
    $brand = get_post_meta($post_id, 'brand', false); 
    $brandNeedle = $merk;                   
    if(in_array($brandNeedle, $brand))
        {
            echo 'true<br>';
        }else
        {
            echo 'false<br>'; 
        }
    }
```

This gives me as a result two times `false`.
Which is half good because there are only two companies in my database for testing. If I use a different brand it also shows two `false` results.
the `$brand` array looks like this. Maybe it helps:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        ) 

)

false

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => brand 1
            [1] => brand 2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your array is a php one, the only thing you need is [in_array](https://www.google.es/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fphp.net%2Fmanual%2Fes%2Ffunction.in-array.php&ei=fSwRVb7AOdLpaPyXgpgG&usg=AFQjCNH1NUIPaUCx_2EBdR6ocG1Fa-EETg&sig2=G9mdH-m5Y34hbXDtJvLYew&bvm=bv.89184060,d.d2s)

it works like this:

```
$brands = array('brand1', 'brand2', 'brand3', 'brand4');
$brandNeedle = 'brand2';

if(in_array($brandNeedle, $brands))
{
   // it is on the array
}else
{
   // it is not 
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to check but thank you. This looks simple and usefull. I'll give it a try

Comment: It seems like you have an array inside your brand array, so, what you need is to make the in_array look like , if(in_array($brandNeedle, $brand[0])) , so it searches on the inside array, do you get me ?

Comment: Wow yes. Thank you makes perfect sence and it works.  Great job